# How to trigger win key + h (to enable Dictate) using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, speech-recognition, microsoft-edge, speech-to-text

I want to do speech to text convertion in a web application(based on jQuery). There are some codes available online in which speech to text is working only in Chrome but not on Edge browser.

I see Microsoft Dictate is the only option in Edge browser and also comes with high accuracy. With win key + h, we can enable Dictate option but I want to enable it when clicking a button in the web application.

Can anyone suggest an idea to fire windows key + h combination from javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something similar to Sendkeys? But as far as I know, it's not possible. Because if such a function is allowed to be implemented in the browser, it will be a very big security risk.

Just like something mentioned in this case: [Can I do SendKeys in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988230/can-i-do-sendkeys-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

`Win`+ `H` key combination would not be able be fired from the browser – you would need an API through the browser to activate Dictate but I don't believe there is one specifically for Dictate.

For an alternative suggestion, you could try the [Speech Synthesis API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) which "can be used to […] start and pause speech". This API has wider support than just Chrome.