# click() on a link element returns a TypeError ... why?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to figure out why executing a click() function on an `<a>` tag element returns a TypeError of 'undefined_method'.  For an example, visit this page: http://http://www.google.com/#&q=test .  Now, each search result on this page has a class name of 'l', so if I ask for:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('l')
```

I get a list of all of the search result `<a>` tags. Logically, indexing this array as follows gives me a specific `<a>` tag:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('l')[0]
```

But, what if I want to click on that link?  I would expect the following to work

```
document.getElementsByClassName('l')[0].click()
```

But instead I get the TypeError 'undefined_method'.

Why?  And how would I activate this link?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dispatch a click event into the DOM, you'll have to use the W3C DOM [dispatchEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent) method for compliant browsers and the MS [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method for others. Some browsers may not support either.

If you want to deal with HTML5 browsers, then you can call the element's click method, however you must test for support first and don't be surprised if browsers don't respond. Most view programatic firing of element listeners/handlers as a bad thing.

Probably the best method in this case is as Zhehao Maoto said and set *window.location* property to the A element's *href*, or just let the user click on the link they want and let HTML do its job.

#### Edit

Testing shows that IE supports *click* on A elements so that the click handler is fired and the link is followed (if the handler doesn't return false). In Firefox, the handler will be called but the link won't be followed.

In Chrome, an A element does nothing but the button responds. Opera fires the A's click handler and follows the link. So the bottom line is that support is very patchy (not really a surprise).

e.g.

```
<!-- Call click() on link to Google -->
<a href="#" onclick="
  var el = document.getElementById('a0');
  if ('click' in el) {
    alert('found click\n' + el.click);
    el.click();
  }">Click link</a>

<!-- Call click on button with onclick handler -->
<a href="#" onclick="
  var el = document.getElementById('b0');
  if ('click' in el) {
    alert('found click\n' + el.click);
    el.click();
  }">Click button</a>

<a href="http://www.google.com" id="a0">Google</a>

<button onclick="alert('click!!');" id="b0">button</button>
```

Comment: thank you!  this is what I needed.  turns out there's a simple example of using dispatchEvent here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648928/javascript-simulate-a-click-on-a-link/649261#649261 .  using an approach like that is now doing just what I hoped for.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that javascript anchor objects do not have a "click()" method. If you want to follow the link programmatically, the easiest way would be like so.

```
window.location = a.href; // assuming a is an anchor object
```

This takes the link's url (the href attribute) and redirects the browser to that location by setting `window.location`.

Comment: If the intention is to follow the link, the best method is to let the browwser follow the link. ;-)

Comment: Ha, right. The best way to follow the link is to click it. I will revise.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `.click()` method (I believe) on a link will have no effect unless an action is bound to the `onclick` event. 
You want something like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('l')[0].onclick();
```

If what you're attempting to do is *follow* the link, rather than activate an `onclick` action, do this:

```
window.location.href = document.getElementsByClassName('l')[0].getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: You are not correct about [click](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-click) **certainly** failing without jQuery. It is a method of the [Element interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#htmlelement) in HTML5.

Comment: onclick() is throwing its own TypeError: property_not_function .  I'd rather activate a click on the link rather than just extracting the href and pointing the browser there, but that would work if a click cannot be activated.  thx!